# How to ignore a dependency in dependency-lock-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

In my maven project I want to implement dependency-locking.
One approach I've found is using [dependency-lock-maven-plugin](https://github.com/vandmo/dependency-lock-maven-plugin).

My project has multiple maven modules.

> parent
>
> - core
> - service
> - third-maven-module

When I run `mvn clean package` it will generate a new `core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` every time.

Now apart from checking version dependency-lock-maven-plugin also checks SHA, which in this case gets changed every time & then the plugin throws error stating SHA is different.

Now to avoid this in plugin's version [0.0.78f56707b3a1d639c8e769bba1686587e9a8956](https://github.com/vandmo/dependency-lock-maven-plugin/tree/release-0.0.78f56707b3a1d639c8e769bba1686587e9a89564-1) we can simple add below lines:

```
<configuration>
  <ignore>
    <dependency>com.myservice:core:*</dependency>
  </ignore>
</configuration>
```

It works but now I can see that this version has [vulnerabilities](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/se.vandmo/dependency-lock-maven-plugin/0.0.78f56707b3a1d639c8e769bba1686587e9a89564), so I want to use the latest version 1.0

But it looks like the configuration to ignore a dependency has been changed & [documentation](https://github.com/vandmo/dependency-lock-maven-plugin/tree/master) does not says much.

Please suggest how can I ignore a dependency in dependency-lock-maven-plugin.

Comment: There is new configuration item: `dependencySets` in  mentioned documentation - please try it

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski, maybe I'm doing something wrong, but its not working. Does it look correct to you? 
<configuration>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <includes>
        <include>com.myservice:core:*</include>
      </includes>
      <version>use-project-version</version>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</configuration>

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski, ignore previous comment. It worked with `<integrity>ignore</integrity>`